# EveryListView in the App Refresh Themselves by IME Keyboard Lifting Up, and Leads to SOF Exception

Tags: android, listview, ime

i have a problem with the IME of phone, Whenever i click on an edit Text, and so KeyBoardLifts up, every ListView in my Activity refreshes itself, I could Prevent the app View being Lifted Up EveryTime With KeyBoar, Using a Straight Height to the Layer, But Still They Refresh Themselves, i have these parameters on my MainActivity :

```
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

and here is my EditText :

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/message_bar" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TextFeild"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.13"
            android:background="@drawable/message_field"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Write here"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textFieldColor" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
```

This Refreshes Cause my App to Throw StackOverFlowException :

```
   09-20 08:15:23.519: E/AndroidRuntime(8223): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   09-20 08:15:23.519: E/AndroidRuntime(8223): java.lang.StackOverflowError
   09-20 08:15:23.519: E/AndroidRuntime(8223):  at 
   android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
   09-20 08:15:23.519: E/AndroidRuntime(8223):  at   
   android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
   09-20 08:15:23.519: E/AndroidRuntime(8223):  at 
   android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
```

How can i Prevent MyListView's being Refresh by Just KeyBoard Lifting Up?!

Comment: well it seems to be Fixed by adding this parameter :   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustNothing"  but know when i start app , it automatically liftsup the keyboar for no reason ! familiar?

Comment: I believe it's because your EditText box is requesting focus with `<requestFocus />` which immediately prompts the keyboard to lift up